# How to make nested subgrid paint faster in chrome? or how to make horizontal level align orgChart?

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs2, orgchart, subgrid

I want to make orgChart with requirements:

- horizontal level align
- expandable node
- node height base on same level node heightest content
- vertical text
- clickable node

I use the plugin [vue-org-tree](https://github.com/hukaibaihu/vue-org-tree),
and the horizontal level align is not support, so I have to do some modification.

the html from the plugin is like:

```
.org-tree[display=table] #wrapper
  .org-tree-node[display=table-cell] #root-node
    .org-tree-node-label
    .org-tree-node-children[display=table]
      .org-tree-node[display=table-cell] #nodeA
        .org-tree-node-label
        .org-tree-node-children[display=table]
          .org-tree-node[display=table-cell] #nodeC
            .org-tree-node-label
            .org-tree-node-children[display=table]
      .org-tree-node[display=table-cell] #nodeB
        .org-tree-node-label
        .org-tree-node-children[display=table]
          .org-tree-node[display=table-cell] #nodeD
            .org-tree-node-label
            .org-tree-node-children[display=table]
```

I want to make sibling node(nodeC and nodeD) align, so I change the wrapper to `grid` and node to `subgrid`, but it become so slow on chrome(ok on firefox)

In devtool Performance, most of the time is on Layout. [image]

did I use the subgrid wrong? or did there have other way to make it work?

| display table | display grid |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

reproduce: [code pen](https://codepen.io/BIgiCrab/pen/dyryNJN)

thanks for response :D